# Can LinkedIn's access token renewal flow be performed on the server?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, linkedin-api

In the Facebook's Graph API, once we have initially authenticated the user, we can interact directly with the API (from the server) to obtain a long-lived page access token.  This long-lived page access token never expires. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/)

In reading LinkedIn's documentation, it appears that it is impossible to obtain an access token with an indefinite (non-expiring) access token.  It seems that they expire every 60 days.  However, these access tokens can be refreshed before the 60 days is up.

What isn't entirely clear from the documentation is whether or not the access token renewal can be performed on the server alone without the client's interaction.  The language of the documentation suggests that the interaction of the client (browser) is required, but nothing is explicitly stated.

So, my question is, is it possible to renew a LinkedIn access token using the server alone, without the interaction of the client (browser)?

Relevant LinkedIn reference material: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/handling-errors-invalid-tokens

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As it turns out, the access tokens of linkedin can not be refreshed without having linkedin user logging in to linkedin. Please refer to the first comment [here](http://developer.linkedin.com/forum/refresh-accesstoken-using-url) by LinkedIn employee which clearly states a note that `"this refresh will only work if the user is still logged into LinkedIn (authenticated) and the current access token isn't expired. Otherwise, the user will be presented with the login dialog again."`

I guess that is now a major issue for those who were previously  storing the linkedin access tokens to database for later use.

I am mentioning few links here which refer to the issue with refreshing linkedin oauth2 tokens (hope this makes it clear for everyone who is struggling with the same issue):

[1) This refresh will only work if the user is still logged into LinkedIn (authenticated) and the
current access token isn't expired. Otherwise, the user will be presented with the login
dialog again.](http://developer.linkedin.com/forum/refresh-accesstoken-using-url)

[2) There is no way to refresh the token using the old authentication token/secret. User
needs to log into linkedin in order for you to refresh the tokens. We use this flow as it
protects our members and their data in the best possible manner.](http://developer.linkedin.com/forum/re-authenticate-users-access-token-using-cron)

[3) Refreshing an access token is very simple and can happen without an authorization
dialog appearing for the user. In other words, it's a seamless process that doesn't affect
your application's user experience. Simply have your application go through the
authorization flow in order to fetch a new access token with an additional 60 day life span. When the following conditions exist:
-User is still logged into Linkedin.com
-The current access token isn't expired (within the 60 life span)
We will automatically redirect the user back to your redirect_uri without requiring them to reauthorize your application. If they don't exist, we'll prompt them to login and then redirect
them.](http://developer.linkedin.com/forum/oauth-access-token-expiry)

[4) We have also standardized the duration of the authorization tokens. Previously, members
could choose to grant tokens that were as short as one day or as long as forever. Now all
tokens are 60 days in length, with the ability for you to extend them in a series of rolling 60 day increments whenever the member comes back to your application. To prevent a bad user experience in your application, be sure to proactively refresh tokens and elegantly route any expired tokens through a refresh flow.](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/member-permissions-migration-guide)

[5) As long as the user is logged into LinkedIn and their current access token hasn't expired, you can fetch an access token with a 60 day lifespan the next time the user comes to your application.](http://developer.linkedin.com/blog/tips-and-tricks-refreshing-access-token)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  You'll note that the statement you've found is still a bit ambiguous - it could be construed to mean, for example, that as long as the user still has an active session *somewhere*, your backend code can independently connect to refresh the token, without the client's cookies and such being present.  For what it's worth, the conclusion I've come to is that the client *does* have to be part of the token renewal process.  In fact, unfortunately, I'd be very surprised if this were not the case.

Comment: @rinogo, Yeah, you are right. The user must have to be the part of token renewal process, so one can't achieve it from server-side alone.

Comment: most of links are dead

Comment: I find this approach very disappointing when the only thing I want to do is to retrieve the number of followers for a Wordpress widget. If Linkedin currently offers a plugin script that lets you embed a follow button with number of followers, without all the authorization hassle and no user interaction required, why is it so damn complicated to do the same on our own to be able to personalize that damn ugly button? I even tried the approach of using MutationObservers and personalize it from frontend, but that damn ugly button is behind 3 iFrames... It's ridiculous!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and the LinkedIn docs and forum posts are confusing, but I'm pretty sure now that it's not possible to do it programmatically without user intervention (i.e. the user needs to login to your app via LinkedIn auth to refresh the token).

Comment: That's what I has feared... Have you implemented anything to help make this reauthentication process smoother / less inconvenient for the user? I'd be interested to hear more about your workflow!

Comment: Even I was looking for the same, but I think that there is not way to refresh oauth2 linkedin tokens without users' intervention. I came to know that one can refresh Facebook tokens in that way, but unfortunately it's not possible with linkedin it seems.