# LinkedIn access token retrieval

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

The website I'm building needs to display company page updates.
This needs to work for all users without the need to log in to LinkedIn (or even have a LinkedIn account).

I created an app and I can run the REST API call by passing the access token, which is all great and as expected.

However... to initially get the access token I need to get the authorization code, which, from what I can see, I can only get by logging in as a LinkedIn user in the browser. Is there a work around for this? I could do this initially manually, but the access token expires in 60 days and to renew it I, again, need to be authenticated. I need full automation in the background with no interaction of users with LinkedIn. Is that possible with LinkedIn API?

Answer (score 0):

An end-user (Referred to as the Resource Owner) needs to provide consent for delegation to your application (OAuth Client) for access to his data from the Resource Server.

Before your access token expires, Linkedin does allow your app to [Refresh your Access Tokens](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2) which allows your app to fetch a new Access Token.

As it turns out, the access tokens of [linkedin can not be refreshed without having linkedin user logging in to linkedin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20635921/88122) as discovered in another answer.

-jim

Comment: An end-user in this case would be me, as the website is making the requests on my behalf. Once granted access to app I can get authorization code and access token, but how can I refresh the token automatically from the website?, is there a way to programmatically authenticate in order to get the refreshed token?, I understand user needs to be authenticated for this...

Comment: As it turns out, the access tokens of linkedin can not be refreshed without having linkedin user logging in to linkedin as discovered in another answer.