# Avoid login prompt for Company data with Consumer Partner?

Tags: linkedin-api

We are trying to show the company updates done for our company on LinkedIn in the companies intranet. After visiting the developer site, we are able to create the token and pull the required information. The challenge is with the login prompt that would come up on the intranet home page. We want to avoid it.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20484815/can-linkedins-access-token-renewal-flow-be-performed-on-the-server/20635921#20635921) mentions we need a token (that we have) and also user should be logged in to LinkedIn. So we guess it is a limitation.

However, the developer site mentions about 'partnership with Linkedin' and says if you become a consumer partner following is possible. It says you have higher functionality and thresholds.
"*Create personalized and engaging user experiences for your audience by combining LinkedIn data and functionality into custom websites and mobile applications*"

We tried reaching to Linked Developer Support with no response from them. Can anyone here confirm if we can  **Avoid login prompt for Company data with Consumer Partner?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about LinkedIn's terms, not a technical question.

Comment: Hey Ganesh, I am looking for technical solution to the issue I am facing. If anyone here has exposure to "additional functionality" that LinkedIn gives after getting into consumer partner, they can help on on how to do it.